# Nesting HTML tags using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm in the process of learning JQuery, and I'm looking to have a list of links that trigger another Javascript function when clicked.  The code I have right now (below) makes the `<li>` tags successfully, but the inner JQuery is returning an object ("1. [object Object]") instead of the text with a link tag wrapped around it.

```
$('<li></li>', {
    text: $('<a></a>', {
        text: data[i].name,
        onclick: 'doSomething()'
    }),
    id: 'response'
}).appendTo('ol.responseList');
```

Your help's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `html` instead of `text`.

```
$('<li></li>', {
    html: $('<a></a>', {
        text: data[i].name,
        onclick: 'doSomething()'
    }),
    id: 'response'
}).appendTo('ol.responseList');
```

P.S. I suggest not using `onclick` attributes to bind events.  Use jQuery's event API.

```
$('<li></li>', {
    html: $('<a></a>', {
        text: data[i].name
    }).click(doSomething),
    id: 'response'
}).appendTo('ol.responseList');
```

UPDATE: If you want to pass `i` to `doSomething`, you need to do something like this (outside of the loop):

```
function createFunc(i){
    return function(){
        doSomething(i);  // this will be the correct value of `i`
    };
}
```

And then do this:

```
$('<li></li>', {
    html: $('<a></a>', {
        text: data[i].name
    }).click(createFunc(i)),  // Yes, this should be `createFunc(i)`, it returns a function
    id: 'response'
}).appendTo('ol.responseList');
```

Comment: One more question, @Rocket, if you don't mind: if I wanted to pass _i_ as an argument into `doSomething`, how would I do that properly?  Simply having `.click(doSomething(i))` causes that method to be called every time the JQuery creates a list item instead of when the item's clicked.

Comment: Enter button == submit messed me up; comment fixed above.

Comment: @Benjin: You'd need to make an anonymous function `.click(function(){doSomething(i)})`.

Comment: That didn't work either.  It now waits until the correct time to call the function, but it always passes the same argument - the final value of _i_ - rather than the index of the list item I clicked.

Comment: @Benjin: Oh yeah, that's a classic JavaScript problem.  You need a closure, a function that returns a function.  Check my edit to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Continue to append to the created elements.  `html` might work too, but I think it is clearer to append:

```
$("<li>", {id: 'respose'}).append(
   $("<a>", {text: data[i].name, onclick: doSomething})
).appendTo('ol.responseList');
```

Comment: `onclick: doSomething` doesn't do what you think it does.  It will make the `onClick` attribute equal to the string `"function(){...}"`.

Comment: @Rocket what?  Doing this will make clicking `a` execute a function named `doSomething`.

Comment: That's the thing, no it won't.  You're setting the `onclick` attribute of an element, which is a string.  So, what happens is that `doSomething` is converted to a string, and then set as the attribute.  It will make something like this `<a onclick="function(){...}"></a>`, which as you can see, doesn't work.

Comment: @Rocket I guess that should just be `click` then

Comment: `$("<a>", {text: data[i].name}).click(doSomething)` would work :-P